# Should there be Storage in .gitignore? Laravel

Tags: laravel, git, storage

In my store method, I give the opportunity to add images, it is loaded into the database normally, but it does not appear in storage. Maybe the reason is that it is in `.gitignore`?

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
      $post = $request->all();
      $post['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;

      if ($request->hasFile('img')){
        // unset($post['img']);
        $filename = 'img_'.Auth::user()->id.time().'.'.$request->file('img')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $post['img'] = $request->file('img')->storeAs('posts', $filename);
        }

      Post::create($post);

        return redirect()->route('index');
    }
```

P.S. I ran `php artisan storage:link` and changed `local` to `public` in `filesystems.php`.

Comment: what would `.gitignore` have to do with it?   go into your file manager and see if the file is there

Comment: I looked, it’s empty.

Comment: `.gitignore` does not remove files or something. It just allows to specify files, which `git` should ignore. So rather troubleshoot your code, whether there are some errors while saving files.

Comment: Understood thanks. I don't have much experience with git, so I decided to ask just in case.